# Optimistic Locking: multiple request to save one data

Tags: angular, database, optimistic-locking

[stack blize](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klqbtv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name" (blur)="onBlur()"> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="data.aa"
  (ngModelChange)="handleClick()"> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="data.bb"
  (ngModelChange)="handleClick()">
</div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class MyObject {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  aa: boolean;
  bb: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  data: MyObject;

  ngOnInit() {
    // in real situation, data should come from restful api, or just a new objecy.
    this.data = {
        name: 'qqq',
        aa: false,
        bb: true
      };
  }

  handleClick() {
    // to save data after checkbox clicked.
    // http POST or PUT
  }

  onBlur() {
    // to save data when focus lost.
    // http POST or PUT
  }

}
```

As you can see in this case. When focus lost of the input text,it should cause http request to save the current data. And when click the checkbox, it should also save the data. In this situation, it has problems:

- **focus lost on checkbox**

when you edit the name, and then just click the checkbox. It will cause two events: focus lost and click.
focus lost happens first and it will call `onBlur()` function, the click event will happen next and call `handleClick()` function.

But in `onBlur()` function, it has http request. so it should happen that: the clint haven't got the http response, but the `handleClick()` send another http request of the same data to restful api again. The database has optimistic-lock, it will cause the second request failed.

And, if the data is just a new object, it hasn't been save to database, it's id is null. when focus lost, it should cause http POST, then client get http response, the data got ID. Actually the client won't wait to get the http response, but just call `handleClick()` function ,the data still don't have ID, it will cause another http POST on the same data.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? pls help.

Comment: A better way, in this situation, would probably be to have a submit button which makes a single call with all of the form data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rxjs for such a situation in combination with `debounceTime`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  data: MyObject;

  private saveData$ = new Subject<void>();
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit() {
    // in real situation, data should come from restful api, or just a new objecy.
    this.data = {
        name: 'qqq',
        aa: false,
        bb: true
    };

    this.saveData$.pipe(
      debounceTime(100),
      takeUntil(this.destroy$);
    ).subscribe(() => {
      // http POST or PUT
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.saveData$.next();
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.saveData$.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried, maybe use bufferTime is better if there are multiple datas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "submitting" -flag in your code. That way you won't in any circumstances submit the form more than once. Additionally you can use the same flag to disable the submit button. Check this Stackblitz example I made base on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhojyc

Main point is the submit method:

```
  submit() {
    if (this.submitting) {
      return;
    }
    this.submitting = true;
    console.log("submitting: ", this.submitting);
    const data = {};
    this.http.post("http://yourapi.com", data).subscribe(res => {
      this.submitting = false;
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.submitting = false;
        }, 3000);

      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that in the example you can see how the submit-button is disabled in both cases, when you click the button or the onBlur-event is fired.